# Subject of Email Should changed based on Cell Value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have created a Google script to send an email once the user submits the form. The script is running very well. But one thing that is not proper is the subject of the email. I want the email subject to be changed based on the cell value.

Currently, I am using this script:

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
    const info = e.namedValues; 
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
    const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Final Responses");
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 64).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 65).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
    
    sendEmail(e.namedValues ['Email address'][0],pdfFile);
}


function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  var DOR = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Final Responses").getActiveCell();
  var NOO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Final Responses").getActiveCell();
  var subject = "DTR - KCCO - " + NOO + " - " + DOR;
  var body = "Sir," +  String.fromCharCode(10)+ String.fromCharCode(10) +  "Please find the attached Daily Transaction Report for the outlet " + NOO + " for " + DOR + "." + String.fromCharCode(10) + String.fromCharCode(10)+ "--" + String.fromCharCode(10) + "Thanks & Regards" + String.fromCharCode(10) + "KCCO - Automation Team" ;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'KCCO - Automation Team'
});

}  
  
function createPDF(info) {
  
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ME3EqHOZzBZDBLNPHQxLjf5tWiQpmE8u");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ebglel6vwMGXByeG4wHBBvJu9u0zJeMJ");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1kyFimRMdHQZV85F5P6JyCHv1DQ3KJFv1hx5o7lIcNZo");
  
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
    const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Name of Person}", info['Name of Person'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Date of Report}", info['Date of Report'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Name of Outlet}", info['Name of Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Opening Petty Cash Balance}", info['Opening Petty Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Received}", info['Total Petty Cash Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Closing Petty Cash Balance}", info['Closing Petty Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Paid}", info['Total Petty Cash Paid'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Available Float Cash Balance}", info['Available Float Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Milk for Outlet}", info['Milk for Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cold Drink And Ice Cube Purchased}", info['Cold Drink And Ice Cube Purchased'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Goods Purchased for Outlet}", info['Goods Purchased for Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Staff Milk/Toast etc.}", info['Staff Milk/Toast etc.'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Water Tank Charges}", info['Water Tank Charges'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Repair And Maintenance}", info['Repair And Maintenance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Petrol Expenses}", info['Petrol Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Freight Paid}", info['Freight Paid'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Soya Chaap}", info['Purchase of Soya Chaap'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Rumali Roti}", info['Purchase of Rumali Roti'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Egg Tray}", info['Purchase of Egg Tray'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Other Expenses}", info['Other Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Please Specify Other Expenses}", info['Please Specify Other Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Tip Amount PAYTM & CARD}", info['Total Tip Amount PAYTM & CARD'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cash Sales - Outlet}", info['Cash Sales - Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cash Sales - KCCO App}", info['Cash Sales - KCCO App'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Card Sales}", info['Card Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Credit/Udhar Sales}", info['Credit/Udhar Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Paytm Sales}", info['Paytm Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{KCCO App Sales Razor Pay}", info['KCCO App Sales Razor Pay'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Swiggy Sales}", info['Swiggy Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Zomato Sales}", info['Zomato Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Dunzo Sales}", info['Dunzo Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Zomato Gold Sales}", info['Zomato Gold Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Dine Out Sales}", info['Dine Out Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Cancelled Bill Amount}", info['Total Cancelled Bill Amount'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Sales of the Day - Total of Above}", info['Total Sales of the Day - Total of Above'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Sales of the Day - As Per PetPooja}", info['Total Sales of the Day - As Per PetPooja'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Old Due Receipts  - Cash}", info['Old Due Receipts  - Cash'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Old Due Receipts - Other Modes}", info['Old Due Receipts - Other Modes'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Tip Receipts - Card}", info['Tip Receipts - Card'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Tip Receipts - Paytm}", info['Tip Receipts - Paytm'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 2000}", info['Currency Note of INR 2000'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 500}", info['Currency Note of INR 500'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 200}", info['Currency Note of INR 200'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 100}", info['Currency Note of INR 100'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 50}", info['Currency Note of INR 50'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 20}", info['Currency Note of INR 20'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 10}", info['Currency Note of INR 10'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Other Currency Note/Coins}", info['Other Currency Note/Coins'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Available Cash to Handover}", info['Total Available Cash to Handover'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Credit Bills}", info['Total No. of Credit Bills'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Credit Approval By// Bill No// Total Amount of Credit}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Credit Approval By// Bill No// Total Amount of Credit'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Bills of Credit Recovery}", info['Total No. of Bills of Credit Recovery'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Mode of Payment// Bill No// Total Amount Received}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Mode of Payment// Bill No// Total Amount Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Complementary Bills  During the Day}", info['Total No. of Complementary Bills  During the Day'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No//Reason// Bill No//Amount Settled}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No//Reason// Bill No//Amount Settled'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Cancelled Bills During the Day}", info['Total No. of Cancelled Bills During the Day'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Bill No// Bill Amount}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Bill No// Bill Amount'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.// Bill No// Mode of Payment//Tip Amount Received}", info['S.No.// Bill No// Mode of Payment//Tip Amount Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{No. of Cylinders Received at Outlet}", info['No. of Cylinders Received at Outlet'][0]); 
  body.replaceText("{Timestamp}", info['Timestamp'][0]); 
  body.replaceText("{Email address}", info['Email address'][0]); 
  //body.replaceText("{Total of Cash Denomination}", info['Total of Cash Denomination'][0]); 
  
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName('DTR - KCCO - '+info['Name of Outlet'][0]+ " - " + info['Date of Report'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
    
  return pdfFile;
  
}
```

The link of the Response submitted by a Google form is as below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m6Aca0TcLf5UZ7P9CvAdQDokoazQljsqDT6CGh0K3j4/edit?usp=sharing

I want the Name of the Outlet i.e. F2:F
and Date of Report i.e. C2:C

E.g. if the user submits the form now data will appear in the 37th row so the name of the outlet and report should be F37 and C37.

Please guide.

Comment: You can pass this data to the `sendEmail(DOR, NOO, email,pdfFile)` function like this `sendEmail(info['Date of Report'][0], info['Date of Report'][0], info['Email address'][0],pdfFile)`

Comment: Couldn't get it right...

Comment: made changes to your code - try sending new responses from the form

Comment: Thanks It worked